# Replacing part of the sympy expression

Tags: python, regex, sympy

Suppose I have a sympy expression like this:

```
x = ( 1+ r70f * C2H4 *H+ r71* O)
```

where `r70f, C2H4, H , r71, O` are sympy variables. I want it to change it to the following expression:

```
x = ( 1+ k(r70f) * c(sC2H4) *c(sH)+ k(r71)* c(sO))
```

Basically replace `r_SomeNumber_f` to `k(r_SomeNumber_f)` and replace `C2H4` or `H` or `O` to `c(sC2H4)` or `c(sH)` or `c(sO)` respectively.

I am trying to use regular expressions but `re.sub` need `str`, but they are all `sympy` objects and that is making things complicated!!!

Comment: Show exactly how you run the expression, and your attempt to apply the regex. Your attempt makes no sense whatsoever the way you describe it.

Comment: Why do `r70f` and `r71` get `k` while `C2H4`, `H` and `O` get `c`? What determines which replacement should be made?

Comment: @ctwheels If a variable is of the form `r_SomeNumberOrLetter` then it will get k. If it is a combination of Capital letters and numbers or only capital letters then it will get `c`.

Comment: @PushanSharma What about something like `c2`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm demonstrating two ways to do this: one with symbol trickery and the other with a wrapper function:

```
>>> ns={}
>>> ns["O"] = Symbol("O")
>>> x = S('1+ r70f * C2H4 *H+ r71* O', locals=ns)
>>> # Symbol trickery -- changing the name to have parens in it
>>> print(x.replace(
...     lambda x: re.match('r[0-9]+f', str(x)),
...     lambda x: Symbol('k(%s)' % str(x))))
...
C2H4*H*k(r70f) + O*r71 + 1

# function wrapper
>>> k=Function('k')
>>> print(x.replace(lambda x: re.match('r[0-9]+f', str(x)), lambda x:k(x)))
C2H4*H*k(r70f) + O*r71 + 1
```

NOTE: You said that you were looking for k_number_f but the case of r71 does not end with an 'f' so it isn't changed.

I leave as an extension the conversion of the others which get wrapped with the 'c-function'.